# Python: TypeError: Unhashable Type: List

Tags: python, numpy

I have a code that basically tests which circles in a random distribution of circles in a box touch - touching circles are added to a dictionary as clusters. I keep getting a TypeError when I run this code:

```
leftedge = 0
rightedge = 1
result = []
color = {}
parent = {}
clusters = {}
number = 0

def bfs(vertices, neighbours, source) :

    global number
    number +=1
    clusters[number] = set()
    color[source] = 'g'
    q = []

    q.append(source)

    while q != [] :
        v = q.pop(0)


        for v2 in neighbours[v] :
            if color[v2] == 'w' :
                 color[v2] = 'g'
                 parent[v2] = v
                 q.append(v2)
            color[v] = 'b'
            clusters[number].add(v)


def createclusters(vertices, neighbours) :

    for v in vertices :
        color[v] = 'w'
        parent[v] = -1

    while 'w' in color.values() :
            for v in color.keys() :
                if color[v] == 'w' :
                    bfs(vertices, neighbours, v)


def overlap(c1,c2,r) :
    if ((c1[0]-c2[0])**2 +(c1[0]-c2[0])**2)**0.5 > 2*radius :
         return 0
    return 1

def findclusters(array, radius) :
    d={}

    for c1 in array :
        d[c1]=[]
        for c2 in array :
            if overlap(c1, c2, radius) :
            d[c1].append(c2)

    createclusters(array,d)

    for cluster in clusters.values() :
        l = [i[0] for i in cluster]
        left = right = False

        x = max(l) 
        if x + radius > rightedge :
            right = True
        x = min(l)
        if x - radius < leftedge :
            left = True

        result.append((cluster,left,right))



import numpy.random as nr

array = nr.uniform(size=(10,2)).tolist
radius = 0.1

findclusters(array, radius)

print(clusters)

print(result)
```

When I try and run it, I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/annikamonari/<ipython-input-316-be6c65f2ce89> in <module>()
----> 1 findclusters(array,0.1)

/Users/annikamonari/<ipython-input-309-32f214b46080> in findclusters(array, radius)
      2     d={}
      3     for c1 in array:
----> 4         d[c1]=[]
      5         for c2 in array:
      6             if overlap(c1,c2,radius):

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

For the life of me, can't figure out why. Can anyone figure it out?

Thank you!

Comment: `d[c1]` hashes `c1` in order to make it a dictionary key. Lists aren't hashable, so it won't work.

Comment: Looks like `c1` is a list. Lists are mutable, so they are not reliable dictionary keys. Maybe you can convert it to a `tuple`? More info on: http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys

Answer (score 4):

First, you probably need to call `.tolist()` rather than leaving off the parens.

---

Also, `array` is a 2-dimensional array, which means that when you do...

```
for c1 in array:
    d[c1]=[]
```

...c1 is a list. Lists, being mutable, are not a hashable type (because if they were, the hash could change at any time based on the contents changing, and hash-based data structures aren't designed to handle that) and thus can't be used as a dictionary key.

If you *intended* to use a sequence of values as a dictionary key, you need to make them non-mutable (and thus hashable) first. The easiest way to do this is by converting to a `tuple`:

```
for c1 in array:
    d[tuple(c1)]=[]
```

However, from reading your code, it seems more like you might be wanting to just iterate over the indices of the first array, which means you probably want something like...

```
for index, values in enumerate(array):
    d[index] = []
    for c2 in values:
        # ...
```

or similar.

Comment: Newbie question... when you say * If you intended to use a sequence of values as a dictionary key, you need to make them non-hashable * shouldn't it be "make them hashable"? If not, I need to ask a question myself :D

Comment: @BorrajaX fingers outpacing my mind; I actually meant 'non-mutable' (but yes, hashable would also apply).

Comment: @Amber... Haha... Thanks! I've seen you reputiation and I was like "I've been 3 years thinking keys had to be 'hashable', but if someone with 103k says 'non-hashable', then it must be 'non-hashable'!! And I better retire from python coding!! " **:-D**

Comment: @Amber Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, when I change it to your first suggestion, I get plenty more 'hashable list' TypeErrors - in the createclusters segment in the code above?

Comment: @Amanc For the same reason - you're passing `array` to `createclusters(vertices, ...)`, and then doing `for v in vertices` and trying to use `v` as a dictionary key. You should try to think about exactly what you're wanting to do: looping over a 2-d array gives you one row of the array at a time.

Comment: @Amber The first for loop in find clusters essentially creates a list of the neighbours of c1 according to the test condition from the array . This serves as an adjacency list which along with array represents a graph. How else would you create the graph which is then used in a breadth-first search ?

Comment: @Amber On second thoughts, passing around 'array' could probably be avoided, as `d.keys()` contains that information. Other than that, are there any major problems that you see ? I could be missing something. [In case it wasnt clear, the program finds the connected components of a graph using BFS for traversal.]

Comment: @AshRj Except that the code confuses lists and values a lot - in some cases it seems to think that `c1` is a pair of coordinates, but in other cases it's assigning a larger list of values to it (and/or trying to use a longer list of values as a key).

Comment: @Amber I really dont see what you are pointing out. c1, v and all other local variables are holding 2d tuples. All globals hold either values referenced by those tuples or are lists of tuples. Yes, this is not a good implementation, that i agree on.

Answer (score 2):

As the program expects array to be a list of 2d hashable types (2d tuples), its best if you convert array to that form, before calling any function on it.

```
temp = nr.uniform(size=(10,2)).tolist()

array = [tuple(i) for i in temp]
```

This should create the input in the required format.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually call the tolist method in your code, you just pass the function itself.

Add the () to call it:

```
array = nr.uniform(size=(10,2)).tolist()
```

Notice that c2 in your code is a list of two numbers, it's not a single number.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error in the copying on my part - I do have the brackets at the end in my actual code.